# Meaning of the access permissions "rws" and "root root" of /usr/bin/sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

In the following access permissions, I am not sure what the second "root" stands for.

The first one is the owner who has permissions `rws` (what does s stand for?) and the second one is the group named root. Is it a special group in which only the root user is member?

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 157760 Jan 11 2016 /usr/bin/sudo
```

If I am wrong, then what is the meaning of the above access permissions?

Comment: You can find some good information about File Attributes [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Viewing_permissions)

Comment: @ThatGuy <3 the Arch wiki. I think our permissions [tag wiki](http://askubuntu.com/tags/permissions/info) is quite helpful too.

Comment: @Zanna Oh excellent! I'll have to have a browse around :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `s` in `rws` stands for `setuid` meaning **set user ID**. This is a special permission bit that allows the program, when run by any user, to be run with the *effective* UID of the owner, in this case, root. So when you as a normal user run the `sudo` executable, you effectively do so as root. This permission bit is a security risk, and should only be applied where absolutely necessary.

Explanation of the `setuid` bit from [*The Linux Command Line* by William E. Shotts Jr](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php/):

> When applied to an executable file, it sets the effective user ID from
>   that of the real user (the user actually running the program) to that
>   of the program's owner. Most often this is given to a few programs
>   owned by the superuser. When an ordinary user runs a program that is
>   "setuid root" , the program runs with the effective privileges of the
>   superuser. This allows the program to access files and directories
>   that an ordinary user would normally be prohibited from accessing.
>   Clearly, because this raises security concerns, the number of setuid
>   programs must be held to an absolute minimum.

The second `root` in the listing is the *group* that owns the file, and yes, only the user root is in the group root:

```
$ getent group root
root:x:0:
```

Here's an example of a file that has different user and group ownership:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 1456 Nov 22 20:08 /etc/shadow
```

This means that the file can be read and written to only by root, but members of the group **shadow** may also read the file.